# Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement when binding the same variable

Tags: php, select, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to list exact results of a search followed by a list of similar sounding results. The similar sound results shouldn't list the exact results, whereas SOUNDS LIKE does include them. How do I exclude the exact results from the SOUNDS LIKE results?

my second search looks like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM memberlist WHERE surname <> ? AND surname SOUNDS LIKE ? ORDER BY surname ASC,firstname ASC,yearstart ASC,yearleft ASC");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['searchsurname']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {$rows[] = $row;}
```

This results in all sorts of errors:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in...
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool in...

Comment: You have two placeholders but you bind only one variable

Comment: provide the variable for  `surnamesounds` `$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['searchsurname'],'$_POST['surnameSOUNDS']);` and I think `surname SOUNDS` is only `SOUNDS` or `surnameSOUNDS` or `surname_SOUNDS` correct it too

Comment: You have wrong number of bind values, which causes the error as other already pointed. On the other hand, using SOLR search engine can be better for searching suggestions and/or similarities.

Comment: While I appreciate my code was wrong, the question was: How do I exclude the exact results from the SOUNDS LIKE results?